# error parsing JSON response Cocoa error 3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post

when i want to post json to the web server, it will crash and show:

```
Warning, status code of response was not 200, it was 400
2014-03-20 01:15:54.407 iBeacons[6669:60b] error parsing JSON response: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x156b6440 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

2014-03-20 01:15:54.408 iBeacons[6669:60b] returnString:

400 Required String parameter 'beaconsMapping' is not present Required String parameter 'beaconsMapping' is not present

```
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:sendData]) 
    {
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"1");
    NSData *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization 
    dataWithJSONObject:sendData options:
    NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSLog(@"2");
    NSString *json=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    NSString *reqData=[@"beaconsMapping=" stringByAppendingString:json];
    NSLog(@"%@",reqData);
    NSData *postDatas=[NSData dataWithBytes:[reqData UTF8String] length:[reqData length]];
    NSString *postLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postDatas length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestPost=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSLog(@"%@",dataUrl);
    [requestPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestPost setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [requestPost setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [requestPost setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestPost setHTTPBody:postDatas];

    NSError *requestError=nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestPost returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    if (requestError == nil) {
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                NSLog(@"Warning, status code of response was not 200, it was %d", statusCode);
            }
        }

        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (returnDictionary) {
            NSLog(@"returnDictionary=%@", returnDictionary);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error parsing JSON response: %@", error);

            NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest error: %@", requestError);
    }


}
```

//my json output:

```
beaconMapping=[
    {
        "floorplanId": "mcc",
        "id": "mcc.b",
        "beaconIds": [
            {
                "distance": "3.873",
                "beaconId": "identityId:Major: 44643, Minor: 29271 x:23.6 y:-21.3 z:-50.2"
            }
        ],
        "locationId": "b"
    }
]//thewebserverrequirestheformatlikethat
 [
    {
        "floorplanId": "mcc",
        "locationId": "c",
        "id": "mcc.c",
        "beaconIds": [

        ]
    },
    {
        "floorplanId": "mcc",
        "locationId": "b",
        "id": "mcc.b",
        "beaconIds": [
            {
                "beaconId": "identityId:Major: 44643, Minor: 29271 x:58.0 y:124.6 z:-360.3",
                "distance": "3.202"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "floorplanId": "mcc",
        "locationId": "a",
        "id": "mcc.a",
        "beaconIds": [

        ]
    }
]
```

//  my websever post code :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/beacons/{floorplanId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Set<BeaconsAtFloorplanLocation> setBeacons(
        @PathVariable("floorplanId") String floorplanId,
        @RequestParam("beaconsMapping") String beaconMappingJson)
        throws Exception {

    Set<BeaconsAtFloorplanLocation> beacons = (new MCCObjectMapper())
            .readValue(beaconMappingJson,
                    new TypeReference<Set<BeaconsAtFloorplanLocation>>() {
                    });

    beaconsLoader_.setBeaconMapping(floorplanId, beacons);

    return beacons;
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: may be the problem is caught by json encoding.

Comment: beaconMapping= equal symbol is not valid in json format

Comment: but my http post need a param called beaconsMapping to receive the sent data, how should I address it. I have sent java web server code on it

Comment: i don't know your php but this link is help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480590/send-parameter-for-php-and-wait-for-response/21480676#21480676

Comment: thanks, I have solved it by deleting some codes.

Comment: with help of the link or resolve your self

Comment: You should take @marciokoko's advice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840

Comment: You should take @marciokoko's advice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing

```
Content-Length

Accept
```

and

```
Content-Type
```

from your code. It may help you.
I had the same issue with json WCF, though my json object was valid json.
I removed all those 3 from code and it worked. The server was not accepting those.
I dont know why..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're not offering the right format data when encoding your json probably.

Are you using json serialization?

Try to use NSLog to see if your data is correct before doing it, you create a NSError *error and put it in your json encode to check what is going on before you post it for your webserver.

Comment: yes, when output data seems right and i post my code and json format, and could u help me check it again? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, delete

```
[requestPost setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[requestPost setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this issue if you're connected to VPN on your device.