# Sending iOS string to PHP

Tags: php, ios, webserver

I am trying to make an iPhone app send a string to my web server. At the moment when I print out $_POST in my php, the array is empty.

This is what I am currently trying;

```
    //NSString *query = @"SELECT name FROM users";
    NSString *query = @"select=name&from=users";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/www/service.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

In the php script I simply do print_r($_POST); I get no error messages, only an empty array. What am I doing wrong? I have tried accessing the two fields separately and it does't work either ($POST['select'];)

Comment: use this link this is hope ful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480590/send-parameter-for-php-and-wait-for-response/21481124#21481124

Comment: try to use `–connection:didFailWithError:` method of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. the answer may be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that print_r prints out an empty array, do you mean that it prints it out an empty array in the browser? If that is the case, don't be concerned - it is not meant to print anything. I was working on something similar and realized that I was debugging it the wrong way.

When you run your simulator in xcode, your php script will get called and $_POST will have a value. If you print_r at that moment it will temporarily hold the value of your two fields (but there is no way to see this on your browser). If you add some NSLogs and print out the response in xcode, you will see that the array is NOT empty.

What I am trying to say is - the only way you should be debugging this should be in xcode, do not look at your browser.

Try this to see your response in the log (this was previously posted - see the link in your first comment);

```
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request      returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    //This is for Response
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

    if(resSrt)
    {
        NSLog(@"got response");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"faield to connect");
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense... I feel silly. I guess I wasn't too sure how the whole post process really worked and didn't read up on it enough. The response I see in my logs contains both my fields so I guess it is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think it's a stupid question. I was also stuck on this for the longest time. I guess it is a very basic issue but I am sure others have seen this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_REQUEST`. May be `$_POST` not works.